# Check for existing value in a Arraylist which contains of values and a class object

Tags: java

I want to create a small Parking System that four classes: one for the user inputs, one with ArrayList class (CarPark) maintaining a list of Slots in the Parking, one ParkingSlot Class and one Car Class.

The ArrayList consist of the values of the ParkingSlot objects. One of the ParkingSlot values is the object of the class Car .
First the user creates a parking slot in the CarPark ArrayList and then has the option to occupy it with a car. Before occupying the program should check if the registration number is already in the CarPark. Here is where I struggle to code the method properly.

I have come up with a method that checks if the registration number is already in the CarPark, but the programm crashes at this point because after the spots are created they are unoccupied and therefore have default Car value = "null". So the program checks the registration input against "null".

The part of the application that takes the user input:

```
System.out.println("Enter the car registration number of the type \"A1234\" ");
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    if(input.matches("[A-Z][0-9]{4}")) {
            if (carParkObj.constrains(input)) == false{
             .......

}
```

This is the method I tried using to check if the number exist in the CarPark ArrayList:

```
public boolean constrains(String searching) {
        for(ParkingSlot slot : slots) {
    if (slot.getCar().getRegistrationNumber().equals(searching)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The ParkingSlot constructor:

```
public ParkingSlot(String newId, String newType, boolean staffMember) {
   this.id = newId;
   this.type = newType;
   this.staffMember = staffMember;
   this.car =null;
}
```

Comment: `slot.getCar().getRegistrationNumber()` will fail if the slot doesn't contain a car.  To be safe, you have to check first that `slot.getCar() != null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
public boolean contains(String searching)
{
    for(ParkingSlot slot : slots)
    {
         if(slot.getCar()!=null)
             if (slot.getCar().getRegistrationNumber().equals(searching))
                 return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Error removed in this:

```
System.out.println("Enter the car registration number of the type \"A1234\" ");
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    if(input.matches("[A-Z][0-9]{4}"))
    {
            if (!carParkObj.contains(input))//if the regno is not already present
            {
             .......

}
```